# Are LLVM "fatal errors" really fatal?

Tags: error-handling, llvm

I'm wondering if LLVM fatal errors are really "fatal" - ie. they invalidate the entire state of the system and are not recoverable.

For example (I'm using the llvm-c interface), the default behavior of the following code:

```
   LLVMMemoryBufferRef mb = LLVMCreateMemoryBufferWithMemoryRange(somedata, data_length, "test", 0);
   LLVMModuleRef module; 
   if (LLVMParseBitcode2(mb, &module) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "could not parse module bitcode");
   }
```

is that if the pointer `somedata` points to invalid bitcode, the fprintf is never executed, but instead the entire process aborts with its own fatal error message on stderr.

However, there is supposedly an interface to catch such errors:  `LLVMFatalErrorHandler`.  However, after installing an error handler, the process still just aborts without calling the error handler.

The documentation in LLVM is very poor overall, and the C interface is barely documented at all.  But it seems like super-fragile design to have the entire process abort in a mandatory way if some bitcode is corrupt!

So, I'm wondering if "fatal" here implies, as usual - that if such an error occurs, we may not recover and continue using the library (for example trying some different bitcode or repairing the old one, for example), or if it is not really a "fatal" error and we can have the `FatalErrorHandler` or some other means of catching and notify, or take other remediating actions, and continue the program.

Comment: There's also `LLVMDiagnosticHandler` but that's completely undocumented, non-obvious to use (function arguments without evident purpose or origin) and I can't get it to work by guessing either.

Comment: There also doesn't appear to be a user mailing list for the LLVM project?   I'm really desperate here. =/

Comment: It's fatal in the sense that the software is no longer behaving as designed. It might be usable for some other purpose, excitingly different from what the authors had in mind, but IMO "known not to behave as designed" is only very slightly different from "fatal". If you have some general idea about what a compiler should do if its input file is corrupt, and that isn't "emit an error message and abort", you might write and submit a patch to LLVM.

Comment: I don't really even understand what you are talking about.  LLVM is not a compiler, and bitcode isn't (always or even usually) an "input file", or any sort of input to a compiler.  I'm asking if there is meaningful error handing in the bitcode reader functionality, or the library is in an inconsistent state and must be reloaded / reinitalized in a new process after when it calls a "fatal" error, before loading other bitcode blobs.  If you know LLVM and can answer, great.   Otherwise...

Comment: Loading a .bc from an [istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/) and encountering an error leaves the [Module](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html) and often the [LLVMContext](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LLVMContext.html) in an indeterminate state. The LLVM developers, who are all compiler developers AFAICT, largely take the view that in such a state, it's best to abort right away, so as to be better able to debug the code that led to the indeterminate state.

Comment: Could you link the source from which you obtained this information?

Comment: (In particular, mandatory abort in this situation is not "better to debug"... it /completely prevents any sort of debugging/, you'd want to capture and print or save to a file / network some sort of diagnostic information... or at least some kind of useful error message.   You'd also want to be able to clean up any system or network resources you've allocated before exiting rudely.   Sounds wrong, especially since there is a generalized error reporting facility that the rest of the project uses that definitely allows this sort of capture)

Comment: Have a look at the coding standards, particularly the [section titled "assert liberally"](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#assert-liberally). Now if you think that's bad advice and increases rather than reduces debugging time, OK, but I think you're being combative rather than inquisitive about it and will ignore any further comments.

Comment: Confusing two things here: `assert()` handling which allows the developers of LLVM to find bugs in LLVM itself, and the error handling facility of LLVM which allows users of the library to write code which receives error states from normal operation of the LLVM library.  "assert liberally" is advice in the LLVM developers guide /for those actively working on LLVM/.  I am a developer using LLVM as a dependency.   Further, the whole point of `assert()` is that you can have it `abort()` at debug time /and then disable this in production/.  This all has nothing to do with my question, though.

Comment: I'm not trying to be "combative", you just really haven't addressed my question, which is about a specific error from a specific part of the API.   You also made a specific claim about the developers of LLVM "largely taking the view" that after bad bitcode fails to parse, the process should abort.  This sounds really weird - and I asked you for a source.  The link you posted does not in any way support that statement. It merely says developers should use `assert()` to validate preconditions at debug time - not that one precondition is that all bitcode a user hands to the library must be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after reading through the LLVM source for 10+ hours and enlisting the help of a friendly LLVM dev, the answer here is that this is not in fact a fatal error, after all!

The functions called above in the C interface are deprecated and should have been removed; LLVM used to have a notion of "global context", and that was removed years ago.   The correct way to do this - so that this error can be caught and handled without aborting the process - is to use the `LLVMDiagnosticInfo` interface after creating an `LLVMContext` instance and using the context-specific bitcode reader functions:

```
   void llvmDiagnosticHandler(LLVMDiagnosticInfoRef dir, void *p) {
      fprintf(stderr, "LLVM Diagnostic: %s\n", LLVMGetDiagInfoDescription(dir));
   }

   ...

   LLVMContextRef llvmCtx = LLVMContextCreate();
   LLVMContextSetDiagnosticHandler(llvmCtx, llvmDiagnosticHandler, NULL);
   LLVMMemoryBufferRef mb = LLVMCreateMemoryBufferWithMemoryRange(somedata, data_length, "test", 0);
   LLVMModuleRef module; 
   if (LLVMGetBitcodeModuleInContext2(llvmCtx, mb, &module) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "could not parse module bitcode");
   }
```

The `LLVMDiagnosticInfo` also carries with it a "severity" code that indicates the seriousness of the error (sometimes mere warnings or perfomance hints are returned).  Also, as I suspected, it is not the case that failing to parse bitcode invalidates the library or context state.

The code that was aborting with the cruddy error message was just a stop-gap to let legacy apps which still called the old API functions work - it set up a context and a minimal error handler which behaves in this way.